# Draw objects without explicit type info as property in Unity inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection, polymorphism

I was having hard time with `UnityEvent`, due to its bad support for many-argument methods and asynchronous logic, so I'm writing my own version of it, which is modeled as a derived class of `ScriptableObject`.

```cs
// Technically there would be more kinds of Callback,
// including a wrapper class for the legacy UnityEvent.
// But for the example's sake I'll just keep thing simple.
public class SimpleCallback : ScriptableObject {
    public Object target;
    public MethodInfo method;
    public List<object> arguments;

    public override IEnumerator Invoke() {
            if(target == null || method == null)
            return null;
                // TODO: Should be asynchronous when method is meant to be a coroutine.
        method.Invoke(target, arguments);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now I'm writing a custom property drawer for it. This drawer should draw each argument of the selected method in the inspector as field slots. (You can assume that I've already filtered out all those methods with non-drawable arguments, so that every argument that we're going to draw must have a corresponding custom `PropertyDrawer` class.)

Here comes the problem: since all my arguments are stored in a `List<object>`, accessing them via `SerializedProperty` would lose the type information; I can manually convert them to `UnityEngine.Objects` and then `SerializedObject` though (regardless of the edgecases of prmitive values like `int`s or `Vector3`s), but doing so would make us lost track of the modified value, since `EditorGUI.PropertyField` doesn't really return the value, rather we'd have to retrieve it with `SerializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties`.

I'm thinking perhaps there are some magical functions that can tell me what is the corresponding `PropertyDrawer` for any given `System.Type`. I can then cached a bunch of children drawers in my callback drawer. Or maybe there's some other better ways? Please let me know, thanks! I'll make it open-sourced on GitHub as a personal toolkit when it's done.

**Edit**: I've managed to implement such thing successfully in Unity. See my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/WangNianyi2001/Nianyi-Unity-Toolkit).

Comment: The last thing you want to put into a **game** is _reflection._

Comment: _"I was having hard time with UnityEvent, due to its bad support for many-argument methods and asynchronous logic"_ - but look what you are replacing it with: _reflection; `List<object>` design smell; lack of contracts._  The irony is that you tagged your question with `polymorphism`.

Comment: @MickyD Hmm... The implementation of `Callback` isn't dependent on its `PropertyDrawer`, at least I've tried to make it so. Only one problem I can think of is that it'll be hard to serialize `List<object>`. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you going to serialize `List<object>`? Isn't the plan collapse at this point?

I guess the whole idea is possible with a new class `SerializedArgument` or alike. It should contain dedicated fields for all possible types of arguments (like `SerializedProperty` has fields for many types). And field of type (just name or index to determine which field is useful for certain argument instance) with it. I think there will be no problem with serialization of `List<SerializedArgument>` and using `SerializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties`. Just this objects could be pretty huge. And I'm not saying that this is a good approach.

About getting `PropertyDrawer` for given `System.Type` or type and `SerializedProperty`. There are methods that allow you to get it. But they are internal for UnityEditor, if I understood it correctly. Look [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/ScriptAttributeGUI/ScriptAttributeUtility.cs).

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializedArgument
{
    public string ArgType;

    //It's not so hard to access SerializedProperties you need from this class
    //And in case of custom property drawers you can draw only one prop at time according to type
    [SerializeField] int m_IntArg;
    [SerializeField] float m_FloatArg;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 m_Vector3Arg;
    //Paste more fields here
    
    public int IntArg
    {
        get => m_IntArg;
        set
        {
            ArgType = typeof(int).FullName;
            m_IntArg = value;
        }
    }
    //Paste more Props here
}
```

Comment: I get your spirit! So this is more or less an editor-independent implementation of `SerializedObject` I guess?

Comment: I wouldn't say about independency. It's better to give an example.